# Analyze video file properties - Ripping Question

Tags: dvd, bluray, ffprobe

I'm trying to see if there is a way to determine if a movie file was ripped from a DVD/Blu-ray. Currently the only way I can check is looking at the ffprobe output and checking the tags property:

1. "_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.14.5 win(x64-release)"

This tells me it was created by the MakeMKV application. If I have the video properties is there a way to check that it's a straight copy of a DVD/Blu-ray?

Example:

1. Bitrate:         (7,209 kb/s)
2. Resolution:      (480p)
3. Bit Depth:       (8)
4. Frame Rate:      (23.976)
5. Color space:     (YUV)
6. Chroma Sampling: (4:2:0)
7. File size:       (4.35 GiB)

Comment: Yes you can google the encoding settings for a bluray and compare it to your file. Looking at your example, this is definitely a rip, since blurays are never (afaik) encoded in 480p (yuck!)